# Pyomo Cannot index a component with an indexed set

Tags: python, indexing, pyomo

I have a Pyomo model that has a sparse set of values but I get the error `Cannot index a component with an indexed set` when I try to index a binary variable according to this sparse set. For a simplified example:

```
model = ConcreteModel()

model.S = Set([1, 4, 6])
model.V = Var(model.S, within=Binary)
```

Comment: I realized I could just pass a list to the variable `model.V = Var([1, 4, 6], within=Binary)` but it seems that passing the set should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line

```
model.S = Set([1, 4, 6])
```

creates an Indexed Set: that is a Set of 3 Sets, each one of which is empty (Pyomo treats positional arguments as indexing sets - just like in your comment about `Var([1,3,5], within-Binary)`).  As it does not make sense to index something by a set-of-sets, you get the exception "`Cannot index a component with an indexed set`".

In your case, it looks like you want a *single* set `S` that has three values.  The correct syntax is:

```
model.S = Set(initialize=[1, 4, 6])
model.V = Var(model.S, within=Binary)
```

Comment: Ok, I see, that makes sense. I was thinking it worked like GAMS where you define an indexed set and then use that for your variables. Thanks!

Comment: You do - or at least can (as you noted in your comment, you do not have to explicitly create sets).  I updated the example in my answer to explicitly show that your original `Var` declaration was correct: your problem was solely in how you were attempting to declare your `Set`.

Comment: @jsiirola can you elaborate on "it does not make sense to index something by a set-of-sets"?