# Pyomo: Loading three dimension set data from json archive error: Cannot index a component with an indexed set

Tags: python, pyomo

In an abstract model from the pyomo library I have three different Sets, each one depending on the previous one and with different dimension size.

```
model.V = pyo.Set()
model.P = pyo.Set(model.V)
model.m = pyo.Set(model.V, model.P)
```

When I try to load the Set values from a JSON file, the following Exception is raised:

```
TypeError: Cannot index a component with an indexed set
```

Here is the code from the JSON file:

```
{
"V" : [1, 2, 3],
"P" : {"1": [1, 2],
       "2": [1, 2, 3],
       "3": [1]},
"m" : {"1": [{"1": [1, 2],
              "2": [1, 2, 3, 4]}],
       "2": [{"1": [1],
              "2": [1, 2],
              "3": [1, 2, 3]}],
       "3": [{"1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}]}
}
```

I suppose the problem is due to the definition of m in the JSON file because the Traceback takes me to the `model.m = pyo.Set(model.V, model.P)` line.

I have checked the [documentation of Pyomo Data Portals](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/working_abstractmodels/data/dataportals.html), but I got no information of 3D JSON data.

Does any one know which is the error in the definition of the 3 dimensional m set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the error of my problem. I found that you have to prove all the possible indices of the sets.

This are the set definitions

```
model.V = pyo.Set()
model.P = pyo.Set(dimen=2)
model.m = pyo.Set(dimen=3)
```

And this is the JSON file:

```
{
"V" : [1, 2],
"P" : [[1, 1], [1, 2],
       [2, 1], [2, 2]],
"m" : [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2],
       [2, 2, 1]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a root-cause for the Exception, but it's not due to data.
You can very easily verify this by creating the `AbstractModel` without passing any data:

```py
from pyomo import environ as pyo

def create_model():
    model = pyo.AbstractModel()
    model.V = pyo.Set()
    model.P = pyo.Set(model.V)
    model.m = pyo.Set(model.P)
    return model
```

Calling `create_model` already fails with `TypeError: Cannot index a component with an indexed set`. Notice I even removed `model.V` from the indices of `model.m`.

I'm not sure why one wouldn't be allowed to use an indexed set to index another component (I tried indexing a parameter and it also fails). [This reply from one of the core developers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49984971/8784382) clearly states that this is a design decision.

This being said, in my experience 95% of the times you use an indexed set you can find a more straightforward solution that doesn't require an indexed set at all.
I have no idea what problem you are modeling/solving, but having a set (`m`) indexed over a set (`V`) and an indexed set (`P`) which itself is indexed over `V` looks overcomplicated.
You can probably move this to a (3D) matrix-like notation or something like that.

If you need more support, please share what the data that you would index over those sets look like (the json file content should be ok).

Comment: I'm trying to implement a research article (https://doi.org/10.1287/trsc.1100.0364) related with harbour transshipment hubs. The model has over 50 different restriction equations and I am afraid it cannot be simplified.

Comment: @damarro, I don't have access to the paper, if you can summarize conceptually why a index indexed over another index is needed, I can try to simplify the mathematical formulation